# Mapping between sets of integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt

I need to map a set of integers into sets of integers.

First off, I want to point out that not all possible sets of integers are taken into account.
Rather, I create the relevant sets that the application will (ever) use - programmatically, only once, and serialize it in a binary file.

Next, I'd construct a `QMap<QSet<int>, QSet<int> > setMap`.

Later on, the application constructs another set of integers (by user input), call it `userSet` and quickly gets `setMap[userSet]`.

Now, the problem is, `QMap` needs `operator <` defined for key types, and obviously `QSet<int>` doesn't have one.

What can I do about it?

Comment: How many different sets do you have? Is the brute force finding out of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sets are static, load them into a table (`QVector<QSet<int> >`), and use the indexes of the sets in that table as keys and values in the map (`QMap<int,int>`) instead of the sets themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide your own overloaded < operator. You can refer to the `Employee` class example in the QMap [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qmap.html). In your case, you need to provide a function like this:

```
 bool operator<(const QSet<int> &first, const QSet<int> &second)
 {
    // your logic to compare the two sets
 }
```

Comment: I think the logic to compare two sets is the problem here.

Comment: QSet uses a hash table based implementation, unlike the STL set which uses a balanced search tree and iterating over a STL set gives values in ascending order. So its easier to compare if you use STL set. You can simply switch to STL map and set ... comparing STL set is simpler, since STL set is a sorted container. Iterating over a STL set will return items in ascending order. But I dont think this is possible with QSet.

Comment: may be you can do this: for each item in set1, verify that the required mapped value exists in set2 or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You always have the possibility of making the key of the map a `QString`. Order the numbers in the set, print them somehow (with an arbitrary separator), and be happy.

Comment: Tried this, and it works but is painfully slow. Helpful idea, anyways! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd convert the sets to ordered lists and map those (and then convert back to sets). It's easier to define a comparison operator for an ordered list than for a set. Of course, this may be too slow for you.

You can also use a hash map.

Comment: Hash map was my idea, too. But, again, qHash() is not implemented for a QSet<int>.

Comment: You can implement it yourself.